# AWS ElasticBeanstalk scaling options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

By default, AWS ElasticBeanstalk scales on `NetworkOut`

However, I am wanting to scale on two scenarios, network out and CPU utilization.

Is there a way to do this so that if either of these exceeds their limit, it will scale?

Comment: As of now, there is no way to do this natively in AWS console.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=556847

Answer (score 2):

In ElasticBeanstalk console `Configuration > Scaling > Scaling Trigger` you can only set one `Trigger Measurement` like `CPUUtilization` or  `NetworkIn` or `NetworkOut` or other options present.

If you need multiple scaling policies, you can add them manually or through `ebextensions` config file to ElasticBeanstalk's `Auto Scaling group` like described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/policy-updating-console.html). Add a [Simple Scaling policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html#StepScaling) or [Target Tracking Scaling policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html).

Add below to ebextension config file to create a Target tracking [scaling policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-policy.html):
`Resources:
  POL:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy'
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: !Ref AWSEBAutoScalingGroup
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      TargetTrackingConfiguration:
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: ASGAverageCPUUtilization
        TargetValue: 80`

To create a Simple scaling policy, you should create a scaling policy and CloudWatch resource like [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html#scenario-as-policy)